# Disable horizontal scrolling while overflow-x is unset

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, scroll

I am having [this issue](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/phone-scrolling-problem/) on the mobile view of my site, where the scroll is sticky and jumpy. I have used the mobile breakpoint code inside (with `overflow-x: unset!important;`) as instructed, and it works great to fix the scroll issue. Unfortunately, it means that I can't also use `overflow-x: hidden` to hide the horizontal scroll. My site has animations and calls for the hidden x-axis scroll otherwise there's whitespace. Anyone have any suggestions on how to get the best of both worlds?

You can find my site [here](https://www.melanie-patterson.com/link-in-bio/). Code is below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1045px){
html, body {
    overflow-x: unset!important;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: unset!important;
    overflow-y: unset!important;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add try something like below..

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1045px){
html, body {
   overflow-x: clip;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost works. On the first attempt to scroll, it still gets stuck. After that, if I wait a second, it can scroll. Once you do get that initial scroll, it continues to work fine. Any chance you have any other ideas?

Comment: This ended up working in the end! I found an offset item in the header that fell of screen in mobile. Appreciate the help!